# OData EndPoint/DataService Using IEnumerable<IQueryable>

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, orm, odata

I am using NHibernate with NHibernate.Linq, and have a bunch of dynamically loading modules each with their own POCO's and Mappings (ClassMap<*POCO*>).

I have created OData services before, but normally with a datacontext and IQueryable as Properties/Getters.

What I want is to create the service by passing in IEnumerable, into the constructor

```
IEnumerable<IQueryable>> queryableObjects;
var dataService = new DataService(queryableObjects);
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable, but it requires some more work. The way to do this is to implement your customer provider. A very nice guide how to do this is here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2010/01/07/custom-data-service-providers/

There are also nice samples as part of the OData provider toolkit, which can be found on [OData SDK - Sample Code](https://www.odata.org/ecosystem/#sdk).

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks
Would be a great edition to umbraco